# Jars required to run hadoop mapreduce word count program in eclipse?

Tags: maven, hadoop, jar

- what are the Jars required to run hadoop mapreduce word count program
  in eclipse?

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/word-count-hello-word-program-in-mapreduce

Comment: I won't downvote you, but if ever a question showed little effort it would be this.  The top Google result from the search "map reduce word count Java" answers your question.